# How to rename a shared Dropbox folder?

Tags: dropbox

I created a Dropbox folder to share named `original` and now I wish it to be named `revised`.  I am able to rename the folder on my computer, but this change is not visible to others, even those that I shared the folder with after renaming it.

How can I rename the folder as it is seen by others?  I would not like to create a new folder of the new name and share that instead, but instead change the original folder in place.  Unsharing the folder and renaming it and then resharing it I see as akin to creating a new folder of the new name and sharing that instead and therefore is also not a desired solution.

Comment: If the answer I posted is not useful then I am not sure if I answered correctly or to the right question; if you would like to expand/revise the question I would be happy to take another shot if I feel I can help.

Comment: @cody.codes The answer is more of a work around in my opinion as it impacts every person you have shared the folder with to lose a shared folder and then accept a new one which is somewhat disruptive in aggregate if it is shared widely. Further, it is undistinguishable for the shared users from creating a new folder and sharing that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully [this](https://www.dropbox.com/help/64/en) will help you out:

> You can rename or move your shared folders just like you would any other folder on your hard drive or via the website. Even if you rename it, the folder will still remain shared. However, changing the name of the shared folder or its location will not change its name or location in the Dropbox of other members.
>
> This is mostly to avoid confusion by maintaining consistency among members of your shared folder. Nobody wants their folders reorganized and renamed without their knowledge. If you do need to rename or move a shared folder for all members of that folder, then you can follow the instructions below.
>
> > On the Dropbox website Rename or move a shared folder for all members
> >
> > - Unshare the folder first.
> > - Rename or move the folder.
> > - Reshare the newly-named or relocated folder.

Answer (score 1):

Though renaming a shared folder itself does not affect the name of that shared folder in the DropBox of other members, you can create, rename or delete subfolders within the main shared folder and this will immediately update in the shared directory tree of other members.